# Electron - call function in preload.js sync or async?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron

I'm trying to convert bigger React JS (webpack 5) project into Electron to use `FS` feature. I was successful to convert it and use `electron-forge` for local testing. I'm learning how Electron work and I would like ask if calling api in `preload.js` is sync or async event. Like this:

**preload.js**

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('saveAPI', {        
    saveAppendSync: (stringToAppend) => {
        console.log("In preload.js before appendFileSync")
        fs.appendFileSync('c:\\temp\\message.txt', stringToAppend) //hardcoded path for testing purpuse
        console.log("In preload.js after appendFileSync")
    }
  })
```

**And than calling this function in application:**

```
console.log("Before saveAppendSync")
window.myAPI.saveAppendSync(fileData) 
console.log("After saveAppendSync")
```

Is this `saveAppendSync` call sync or async event? How to make it sync or do I have to use something like this:

**preload.js**

```
//after fs.appendsFileSync()
ipcRenderer.invoke("file-saved", args)
```

**In application:**

```
ipcMain.handle("file-saved", async (_event, props: string) => {});
```